# Maven dependency: ranges resolving issue

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I want to use a range for the version of some dependency. But I don't really get it how it should be defined for my case.
Here's the results of lookup - `maven-metadata-nexus.xml` file.

```
<versioning>
    <latest>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</latest>
        <versions>
            <version>0.0.13-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>0.0.14-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>0.0.15-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>0.0.16-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>0.0.17-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </versions>
        <lastUpdated>20190826092951</lastUpdated>
</versioning>
```

I want to import the latest 0.1.x dependency, so I thought writing range this way would do the thing

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>[0.1, 0.2)</version>
</dependency>
```

However, maven says that there's no version of my artifact available.
Defining range as `[0.1.0-SNAPSHOT, 0.2)` fixes the problem, but I don't really understand why I need to be so specific with the boundary and is it a good practice or not. What's *the right* way to define such ranges?

Comment: Version ranges exist, but fell out of fashion. Explicit updates with the help of the versions-maven-plugin are more common nowadays.

Comment: @JFMeier thanks, it does look better tbh. Could you recommend some articles on release workflow with the help of versions maven plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven treats SNAPSHOT version differently than "normal" versions.

- "normal" (published in a repo) version is typically immutable. It can't be updated nor removed and no matter when you access it will still be the same.
- SNAPSHOT versions are the opposite of that. They can change at any time (think work in progress).

Typically SNAPSHOTs are only to be found in your local repo. If you want to use SNAPSHOTs from remote repo you have to explicitly tell Maven that repo provides SNAPSHOT versions.

With that distinction in mind, [Maven folks have decided](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3092) that

> Resolution of dependency ranges should not resolve to a snapshot (development version) unless it is included as an explicit boundary. There is no need to compile against development code unless you are explicitly using a new feature, under which the snapshot will become the lower bound of your version specification.